# trouble in query

Tags: sql

hey every one i have this record

```
id  date      hours   groupkey
1   1-12-2016  1        NULL
2   2-12-2016  2        NULL
3   3-12-2016  1        3
4   4-12-2016  1        3 
5   5-12-2016  1        3
```

and i want this

```
id   startdate   enddate     hours
1    1-12-2016   1-12-2016   1
2    2-12-2016   2-12-2016   2
3    3-12-2016   5-12-2016   3
```

i am using this query

```
SELECT Max(Isnull(groupkey, id)) AS id, 
       Min(date)                 AS startdate, 
       Max(date)                 AS enddate, 
       Sum(timeoffhours)         AS hours, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Min(groupkey) IS NULL THEN 'No' 
         ELSE 'Yes' 
       END                       Status 
FROM   table 
WHERE  employeekey = 20 
       AND date >= '1/1/2016' 
       AND date <= '12/31/2016' 
GROUP  BY groupkey
```

but it is making one row for null group key please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY Isnull(groupkey, id))` to solve your issue here. You're still grouping on the regular `groupkey`.

Comment: What if `id=3` had `NULL` on `groupkey` ?

Comment: @sagi OP did not clarify this to be the case so I tried to avoid adding complexity based on what *could* be. What if `id=1000` had `1000` on `groupkey`? You can't make assumptions.

Comment: Then multiply it by more :) but with having 1000 rows on the table your query will probably mismatch a few groups .

Comment: @sagi I fully agree. That's why I didn't go through the trouble of adding in any extra logic for it, just because we can't assume. I expect OP to figure this one out if that would be the case, or tell us about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try in dynamic table

```
SELECT 
    id, startdate, enddate, hours, 
    CASE WHEN mingroup IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'YES' END AS status
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MAX(ISNULL(groupkey, id)) AS id, 
         MIN(date)                 AS startdate, 
         MAX(date)                 AS enddate, 
         SUM(timeoffhours)         AS hours, 
         MIN(groupkey)             AS mingroup
     FROM   
         table 
     WHERE  
         employeekey = 20 
         AND date >= '1/1/2016' 
         AND date <= '12/31/2016' 
     GROUP BY 
         groupkey)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Temp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) , _date DATE ,_hours INT ,  groupkey INT)
CREATE TABLE #OutPutTemp (_id INT , _Startdate DATE ,_EndDate DATE,  _Hours INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp (_date  ,_hours  ,  groupkey )
SELECT '1-12-2016' ,1,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT '2-12-2016' ,2,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT '3-12-2016' ,1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT '4-12-2016' ,1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT '5-12-2016' ,1,3 

INSERT INTO #OutPutTemp(_id  , _Startdate  ,_EndDate,_Hours)
SELECT id , _date , _date , _hours
FROM #Temp
WHERE ISNULL(groupkey,0) = 0

INSERT INTO #OutPutTemp(_id)
SELECT groupkey 
FROM #Temp
WHERE ISNULL(groupkey,0) <> 0
GROUP BY groupkey

UPDATE #OutPutTemp SET _Startdate = Startdate
FROM
(
    SELECT MIN(_date) Startdate ,groupkey
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE ISNULL(groupkey,0) <> 0
    GROUP BY groupkey
)A
WHERE _id = groupkey


UPDATE #OutPutTemp SET _EndDate = EndDate
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(_date) EndDate ,groupkey
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE ISNULL(groupkey,0) <> 0
    GROUP BY groupkey
)B
WHERE _id = groupkey

UPDATE #OutPutTemp SET _hours = tothours
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(_hours) tothours ,groupkey
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE ISNULL(groupkey,0) <> 0
    GROUP BY groupkey

)C
WHERE _id = groupkey

SELECT * FROM #OutPutTemp
ROLLBACK TRAN
```